# Most reliable way to get Shopify store name for Shopify API scripttags?

Tags: javascript, shopify

It seems like there's 2 options available, and I wanted to make sure they were reliable ways to get the current Shopify store information:

**Option #1:**

Hijacking `window.Shopify` variable. This provides `shop` variable needed for any api calls (api calls not through Shopify but my server).

**Option #2:**

Shopify passes `shop` to the injected script element like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://myexample.com/js/welcomeBar.js?shop=foobarshopify.myshopify.com"></script>
```

This option is weird because I do not see it being done for every scripttag that I tested from Shopify store, only mine.

Is either option more reliable than the other (or do either cause issues)? Also, please let me know if there is a more reliable way, or if there's more ways missing.

Edit: This is under the assumption that the Shopify app is installed, and I need the `shop` for the current store it is installed on.

Comment: This question is hard to answer. You have an App and it has been installed in a shop, so when that App goes to install any ScriptTag, you have the shop from Shopify. Otherwise you are doing things wrong. 

There is no hijacking window.Shopify and Shopify does not pass shop names to you, when you install script tags Shopify simply uses the Shop from the App.

Comment: @DavidLazar this was under the assumption that the user has installed the Shopify App. I will edit the question to include that. So, using window.Shopify would be present (I'm assuming for all cases) and I'm not sure if shop is always passed through src query.

Comment: What API calls are you speaking of. ScriptTag works without an API call. Are you confusing some other situation here?

Comment: @DavidLazar I just re-edited to clarify. The api calls are for my server and not for Shopify's api service. My api will manipulate the output of Shopify's scripttag.

Comment: Whatever it is your ScriptTag does, since it executes on your server, you know the callback includes the shop.

Comment: I think disconnect here is I am asking for most reliable way to get "shop" so I do not deal with a case where it is missing. There was nothing in Shopify documentation for this. We are on same page that Scripttag executes on my server and I control everything there so I could check if it is not present.

Comment: Point is, your ScriptTag is never called without the shop. So if you receive a call without Shop, it's crap... ignore it.